# How to combined Box plot with scatter plot in tibco spotfire?

Tags: charts, scatter-plot, boxplot, spotfire

I have searched almost all the internet and didnt find an answer of combining box plot with scatter plot in tibco spotfire.

Can anyone help me out in making the combined visualization in which i need to show "scatter plot combined with Box plot"

I need to do the visualization against "Parameter name on x axis" and "parameter value on y axis"

for example: Parameter name: a,b,c ; value: 1,2,3

this parameters are repeating as per the lot numbers: lot 123, 124. one lot will have all these three parameters.

Please help me out by guiding the steps in achieving this mysterious graph in tibco spotfire.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the same things here. Scouring the internet. I'm doing this in Prism for the time being, but I'd prefer this in Spotfire.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).